# Best way to get validator address/fee recipient address for a block

Tags: go-ethereum, flashbots

Is there any other way to get the proposer fee recipient address other than using flashbots relay API? Relay API isn't thorough and for certain blocks, you can miss out on getting the proposer fee recipient.

Web3 geth api only provides details of the "miner", which is the address of the builder, not the proposer.